# Should I create a new address for each transaction?

Tags: transactions, mist, addresses, privacy

It's my understanding, when using bitcoin, it's advisable to generate a new address for every transaction. Is this also the case for Ethereum, and if so, how do I do this with Mist?

Comment: for address you mean one account or no?

Comment: @Gawey what account or no?

Comment: @niskmac Now for me the new address is a new account or you mean other thing no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin is UTXO based, so you can use an HD wallet([BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)) to get a new address for each transaction to protect your **privacy**. However, Ethereum is account based and each account has a single address, but it is possible to implement an HD wallet for Ethereum. I think there is already such wallets as [Jaxx](https://jaxx.io/) which provide such ability.

So to answer you, if your privacy is crucial to you, please use an HD wallet for Ethereum. Mist don't offer this option.

Read more about HD wallets https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84

Comment: OP is asking for a way to do this in MIST.

Comment: there is also eth-lightwallet